# Best books for Contact topology

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, symplectic-geometry

I'm looking for a book on contact topology that is suited for self study.

Could you kindly recommend some literature?

Thanks advance...

Comment: This may not be helpful now, but I tend to use this a lot: https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Other/topologybooks.pdf. Also, I've heard some good things from Dusa McDuff's lecture notes.

Comment: There is a book of A. Cannas da Silva "Lectures on symplectic geometry" and it contains a chapter about contact structures

Answer (score 1):

The canonical reference is Geiges' contact topology. It does not have exercises, but it does have worked out examples. It is a good idea to treat the examples as exercises.